# JBoss7 - How to access VAULT password in code

Tags: java, jboss

Is there a defined way to decrypt a `VAULT` password in a java util class?

I have a bind credential for an `LDAP` login setup on a jboss5 instance and I need to convert it to a jboss 7 instance, but i am getting an Authentication exception error.

**Error**

```
ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042A, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839 ]
```

**local.build.properties**

```
ldap.auth.bindCredential=VAULT::authdevBindCred::password::1
```

**Util.java**

```
String ldapPass = System.getProperty("ldap.auth.bindCredential");
...
ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPass);
```

Comment: Are you or your company part of the Red Hat Support Program?  I see a means of doing it there as a verified solution but not sure I'm able to show the code.

Comment: @JGlass yes I have an account, could you point me to the article? Thanks.

Comment: Sweet!  Not worth providing an answer just for a link but if you get the code working you might answer your question with it - just be careful you don't get in trouble with RH.  Let me know how it goes! [Retrieving stored values from JBoss vault](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/370013)